# CreateJS Container recursion loop for nested Objects

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

I'm an ActionScript developer finally taking the plunge into HTML5 and JavaScript.  I'm using CreateJS as it has a reputation for making an easier transition for folks like me.  I'm trying to create a recursion loop to let me know what nested objects I have on my stage.  I obviously am not there yet.  Could anyone help point out where I'm going wrong?  Thank you.

```
recur(exportRoot);

function recur(thisContainer)
{
    console.log("recur()");
    for(var i=0; i<thisContainer.getNumChildren; i++)
    {
        console.log(thisContainer.getChildAt[i]);
        if(thisContainer.getChildAt[i].getNumChildren !== null && thisContainer.getChildAt[i].getNumChildren !== isNaN())
        {
            recur(thisContainer.getChildAt[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to test if `foo` is `NaN`, use `isNaN(foo)` instead of `foo !== isNaN()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getNumChildren` to see if the child is a container, you should use this:

```
var child = thisContainer.getChildAt[i];
if ( child instanceof createjs.Container ) {
    recur(child);
}
```

---

**Update for easeljs-0.8.1:**

```
    private loopContaneir(objDisplay) {
        for (var i= 0; i < objDisplay.numChildren; i++) {
            var child = objDisplay.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof createjs.Container) {
                loopContaneir(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @olsn, but it still isn't working. Here's what I have now:

    `recur(stage); //I've also tried with recur(exportRoot)
    function recur(thisContainer)
    {
        console.log("recur()");
        for(var i=0; i<thisContainer.getNumChildren; i++)
        {
            var thisChild = thisContainer.getChildAt[i]
            console.log(thisChild);
            if(thisChild instanceof createjs.Container)
            {
                recur(thisChild);
            }
        }
    }`
Sorry for the formatting.  I can't seem to fix it.
Here's what I'm getting in my console:
`recur() `

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of my biggest problems was that I was trying to use `getNumChildren` (a nonexistent property) rather than `getNumChildren()` (method).  I've now gotten it working correctly, thanks in part to @olsn for suggesting `instanceof`.

```
recur(exportRoot);

function recur(thisContainer)
{
    console.log("recur()");
    var containerLength = thisContainer.getNumChildren();
    var thisChild;
    for(var i=0; i<containerLength; i++)
    {
        thisChild = thisContainer.getChildAt(i);
        console.log(thisChild);
        if(thisChild instanceof createjs.Container)
        {
            recur(thisChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it works, you might want to consider, using a variable for `thisContainer.getChildAt(i)` - if you just doing this as a test, it won't matter, but if you use this as a utility-method that is called often in your app, using a local variable is quite a bit faster than making 3x the method-call `getChildAt` which is even on another object. And it's also cleaner ;-) (you might notice a difference on your phone probably, on your computer not so much any more, since the Javascript engines are getting faster and faster now) - But anyways, gz that it works now :)

Comment: Thanks.  In ActionScript, it's always been my understanding that a typed `var` statement also carried some overhead, and I've tried to avoid using them in loops when they would be called dozens or hundreds of times.  Perhaps that was misguided?  Perhaps JavaScript is different.  Either way, thanks.  I'll edit the answer per your advice.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I just added the `var` statement before the loop.  Sorry, I'm still somewhat disoriented by the change in languages.  The lack of strict datatyping in particular.  Thanks for the help and the patience.